# Filtering on tag does not seem to work when fetching tracks by specific app

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I'm trying to fetch tracks by a specific app, and at the same time filter by a certain tag. It seems like all tracks from the app are returned regardless of the tag parameter. If I query all tracks (i.e. don't specify an app id) the tag filtering works as expected. This is the code I'm running:

```
var appId = 12345; // Real app id in the actual code.
SC.get('/apps/' + appId + '/tracks', {
    limit: 10,
    filter: 'public,streamable',
    tags: 'Acid House'
}
```

Is this an API bug, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering on tags is a feature of `/tracks` endpoint. I am sorry if it's not immediately clear from the API reference or SDKs documentation.

Comment: Can any kind of filtering be done when using the `/apps/app_id/tracks` endpoint?

Comment: Nope, you'll have to filter them on your side.